# Image of a Borel set under monotonic functions

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

Suppose $B$ is a Borel set and $f$ mapping  from $B$ to $R$ is a non decreasing function.Prove that $f(B)$ is a Borel set.

f is a Borel measurable function because the inverse image of $(a, \infty)$ will be of the form $(t, \infty)$ or $[t,\infty)\cap B$ which is a Borel set. I cannot define inverse function because it may not be strictly increasing. How do I proceed?

Comment: This is surely overkill, but there is a theorem in Descriptive Set Theory asserting that the image of a Borel set under an injective function is also Borel. A reference for this is Kechri's *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*

Comment: So if its not injective, f(B) might not be a borel set?

Comment: No, this can fail even for continuous $f$. This was a famous mistake done by Lebesgue in the early 20th century.

Comment: @pooja - That's correct, but notice monotone maps are always injective. $x \neq y$ implies $x < y$ (without loss of generality) so $f(x) < f(y)$. In particular, $f(x) \neq f(y)$

Comment: Monotone doesnt mean strictly increasing function.even constant functions come under increasing functions

Comment: I should clarify that when I said "injective function" in my first comment, I meant injective *Borel* function. Also, this is Theorem 15.1 in Kechris

Comment: I looked around to see if I could find a proof that doesn't rely on the descriptive set theoretic fact that @Reveillark mentioned, and I was unsuccessful. Here's a [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957572/monotone-functions-and-borel-sets) that does it in detail, though.

Comment: A proof of the result mentioned by Reveillark can  be found in Cohn's Measure Theory.